# Help Close Duplicates of "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) for a few months now to close the following questions:

- <del>[cygwin's ssh-add returns "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695337/cygwins-ssh-add-returns-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-age)</del> (closed)
- <del>[Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent)</del> (closed)

as duplicates of this older question

- [ssh-agent error "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/how-to-run-git-ssh-authentication-agent)

My close votes expired a long time ago, and I've already asked for close votes twice in chat, but the duplicates just aren't getting enough close votes. I picked [ssh-agent error "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/how-to-run-git-ssh-authentication-agent) as a canonical because the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086756/456814) does the best job of explaining *why* `ssh-agent` is required to run.

After the duplicates are closed, I'd also be interested in having some of the answers from them merged into the canonical.

If you think the questions should be closed, vote to close them, or comment/answer if there's a better canonical question, or if they shouldn't be closed.